# Django: How to filter objects on values coming from functions?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: `Company` and `Service`. In order to filter on `Service` objects based on the `company website`, I do the following:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id = some_id)
service = Service.objects.filter(website = company.website)
```

Now, suppose I have a function `f(website)` that only returns the `hostname` of the website, and I want to filter for instances where `f(website of the service)` would be equal to `f(website of the company)`. Now, if I do the following:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id = some_id)
service = Service.objects.filter(f(website) = f(company.website))
```

it gives syntax errors (obviously).

What is the proper way to do this simple filtering?

In both `Service` and `Company`, the `website` is a normal `string` and does not have any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking for something like this:

```
service = Service.objects.filter(website__hostname = company.website.hostname)
```

Where hostname is a field of Website.

Comment: Well, that `website` in both `Service` and `Company` is just a normal string, it does not have any fields.

Comment: Can you show how website and hostname are related? i.e. provide an example or share you `f(website)` code?

Comment: f("https:/ /www.something.com/") returns "www.something.com"

Comment: Btw, let's not focus on the `hostname` part. Think of the function `f` as one where if you enter some string `a` as argument, then it returns some *other* string `b`. Now, all I want, is to filter those `Service` objects where `f(service's website field's value)` equals `f(company's website field's value)`

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the examples given so far, we have constructed filters that compare the value of a model field with a constant. But what if you want to compare the value of a model field with another field on the same model?

Django provides F expressions to allow such comparisons. Instances of F() act as a reference to a model field within a query. These references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of two different fields on the same model instance.

For example, to find a list of all blog entries that have had more comments than pingbacks, we construct an F() object to reference the pingback count, and use that F() object in the query:

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.filter(number_of_comments__gt=F('number_of_pingbacks'))
```

[Filters can reference fields on the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: I don't think this helps. How does this translate to my scenario?

Comment: I think your way of writing the code is the wrong one, which I mean from the first post
service = Service.objects.filter(website=f(company.website))